# Routing Error in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, single-page-application

Good Day!

I am experiencing an intermittent issue where the state parameters are being used sometimes instead of the values.

For example:

Link pasted or clicked from emails/files:

https://www.school.com/students/12531/2/report

After loading it will cause error 400 (Bad Request) because the URL becomes:

https://www.school.com/students/:id/:status/:request

The error (400) does not happen all the time i don't know if this is code issue since the routing works (sometimes)

i'm using

AngularJS v1.3.20

ROUTER CODE

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.students')
    .run(appRun);

appRun.$inject = ['routerHelper'];
/* @ngInject */
function appRun(routerHelper) {
    routerHelper.configureStates(getStates());
}

function getStates() {
    return [
        {
            state: 'students',
            config: {
                url: '/students/:id/:status/:request',
                templateUrl: 'app/students/studentsView.html',
                controller: 'studentsController',
                controllerAs: 'vm',
                title: 'Students View',
                params: {
                    //Set default value to zero (0)
                    id: {
                        value: '0'
                    },
                    status: {
                        value: '0'
                    },
                    request: {
                        value: 'Default'
                    }
                },
                requireADLogin: true
            }           
        }
    ];
}})();
```

Comment: I'm confused. You're getting 400 or 404? And what exactly is happening? Do you have a default routing configured that is used? The http error should come from a server and not from angular routing.

Comment: Sorry its 400 Bad Request - i've changed it now

Comment: I would begin setting a [defaultErrorHandler](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/classes/state.stateservice.html#defaulterrorhandler) to catch errors from the router. `.config($uiRouterProvider => 
  $uiRouterProvider.stateService.defaultErrorHandler(console.log)
);` I'd also like to see whats going on in that studentsController (but it's too early to say if it's relevant)

Comment: Hi @ippi tried but its not showing in logs since the request url is changed and .net (server side) already catches the error even before the controller/routers execute

Comment: Oh, then I'm guessing the error happens when you reload the page on a "bad url"? If so, that's almost certainly a misconfiguration of the webserver. You want to redirect all your incoming requests to your app which handles all the routing. (Sorry if I'm way off.)